# Accessing the View within the MediaController widget

Tags: android

The Android MediaController widget is composed of a Scrollbar view and a bunch of other views. I want to be able to get to the scrollbar and then resize it. Can someone let me know how I could access it? I can't use findViewById() since the R.java file is in the base Android framework and not accessible in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using getIdentifier(), I can get the ID of the widget by querying the resources. This way, even if the ID changes from device to device or version to version, it'll be looking for the correct ID.

```
final int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mMediaControlsView.findViewById(topContainerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create your own controller. It is not that hard. Even if you were to find the widget ID for the Android open source code:

- device manufacturers may have rewritten MediaController and may have a different widget ID
- older Android devices may have a different widget ID
- future Android devices may have a different widget ID

Relying on internal implementation details like widget IDs and such make your app fragile.